# Need help in creating Json string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, json

I am unable to create a Json string in the following format, please help. Where key value pair can be a number:

```
"tag_container": { "tag1": "Tag1", "tag2": "Tag2", ..... }   
var uploaded = new Uploaded();
var str = "*#Hello* i *#am*  writing a regexp *#h*";
var re = hash_parser(str);  
uploaded.tag_list = new Array;
uploaded.tag_list.tag = new Array;

for(var i = 0; i < re.length; i++)
{
    uploaded.tag_list[i] = new Object;
    uploaded.tag_list[i].**tag** = re[i];
}
```

above code is giving in following format:

```
"tag_list":[{"**tag**":"*#Hello*"},{"**tag**":"*#am*"},{"**tag**":"*#h*"}]
```

Comment: Sorry, can you explain a bit more? First of all, the code does not create a `string` at all. Second, what exactly is the problem with the output format?

Comment: Your code does not make sense. Arrays are created like this: `uploaded.tag_list = []` or like this: `uploaded.tag_list = new Array()`. Likewise, objects are created like `{}` or `new Object()`. You also seem confused about JSON. Did you want to wrap your JSON examples in single quotes? Like this: `'"tag_container": { "tag1": "Tag1", "tag2": "Tag2", ..... }'`

Comment: thanks for the quick reply i am able to generate in "tag_list":["#Hello","#am","#h"] in javascript in following formate but i need in this formate "tag_list": { "tag1": "#Hello", "tag2": "#am", ..... }

Comment: I think he's trying to say that he wants to have a JSON "associative array", which is accomplished in Javascript by using objects. As I say in my answer, this is done by setting `tag_list` to an object, and using this notation to enter key=>value pairs: `uploaded.tag_list['tag' + (i+1)] = re[i];`

Answer (score 3):

I *think* maybe you might be confusing JSON with object literal syntax.

Instead of:

```
"tag_container": { "tag1": "Tag1", "tag2": "Tag2", ..... }
```

you should just be using normal JS syntax:

```
var tag_container = { "tag1": "Tag1", "tag2": "Tag2", ..... }
```

... but it's really hard to tell from your post.  If you know anyone who can help you with your English, it really might help me (and others) understand this question better.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to convert something into JSON is to use `JSON.stringify`.

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify({ tag_container: { tag1: 'tag1', tag2: 'tag2' }});
```

stringify is available in all modern browsers. If you wish to support older versions, the [JSON2 library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) is perhaps the best choice as it provides the same API as the official JSON spec.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is something like this:

```
var reLen = re.length;
uploaded.tag_list = {};

for(var i = 0; i < reLen; i++)
{
    uploaded.tag_list['tag' + (i+1)] = re[i];
}
```

This will output the format you wish to see, i.e.

```
'"tag_container": {"tag1": "*#Hello*", "tag2": "*#am*", "tag3": "*#h*"}'
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all for the all reply and guide my problem is solved in some other way I am sending json string to cross domain

```
string = "hi  @group1 @group2  *user1 *user2 #fs #ffsd #fsdf";
```

and generated json string is

```
{"raw_msg":"hi @group1 @group2 *user1 *user2 #fs #ffsd #fsdf","msg_type":"group","top_msg_id":0,"file_container":{"file1":{"id":"","file_name":"","uri":""},"file2":{"id":"","file_name":"","uri":""}},***"tag_list":["fs","ffsd","fsdf"]***,"link_list":"","image_container":{"image1":{"id":"","name":"Name","uri":""},"image2":{"id":"","name":"Name","uri":""}},"attached_thread":{"thread1":{"title":"","top_id":"","last_id":""},"thread2":{"title":"","top_id":"","last_id":""}},"to_user":["user1","user2"],"to_group":["group1","group2"]}
```